# How to make my discord.js bot show how many servers it is in as it's status

Tags: discord.js

I'd like to have my bot have a status that says how many servers it's in.

For example, `in 6753421 guilds`. I figure you'd make a separate section of code and add `${}` to the status with the name of the function in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `client.setActivity()` and then use the `client.guilds.cache.size` value.
For example:

```js
client.setActivity(`serving ${client.guilds.cache.size} servers`);
```

Comment: Perfect! It would be better if you can mark this answer as correct.